# pdflatex make text unselectable (uncopyable)

Tags: pdftex, copy-paste

How would i go about making the pdf output of a document have unselectable sections? (So you can't directly copy and paste from them). Is there some way of converting all the text into vectors? This is with latex, and pdflatex. I've seen a way to replace the text that is copied, but even that doesn't work in all pdf viewers, and some give the original, so is there just some way to delete the actual text altogether, just leaving the pdf with the vectors of the text?

Comment: This question has been asked a couple of times here.

Comment: @KeksDose, do you have any links to the questions?